# Write a data frame containing a list to csv file

Tags: r, list, csv, dataframe

I would like to save my data `train.user` (213451 obs. of  20 variables. 2 of the variables are lists) as a csv file.

I use:

```
write.csv(train.user, "train_user.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

but an error occurs

```
Error in .External2(C_writetable, x, file, nrow(x), p, rnames, sep, eol,  : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'
```

This is how my data `train.user` looks like. (by using `str`) (showing only part of it)

```
'data.frame':   213451 obs. of  20 variables:
 $ id                     : Factor w/ 213451 levels "00023iyk9l","0005ytdols",..: 100523 48039 26485 68504 48956 147281 129610 2144 59779 40826 ...
 $ gender                 : Factor w/ 4 levels "-unknown-","FEMALE",..: 1 3 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ age                    :List of 213451
  ..$ : num NA
  ..$ : num 38
  ..$ : num 56
  ..$ : num 42
  ..$ : num 41
  .. [list output truncated]
```

It seems like the column `age` is stored as a list, and `write.csv` doesn't accept this format. From my naive intuition, I tried to re-store the column as a data frame with following code, but it failed.

```
train.user$age <- as.data.frame(train.user$age)
```

Error message:

```
   Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "age", value = list(NA_real_. = NA_real_,  : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 213451
```

I also tried `train.user$age <- data.frame(lapply(train.user$age, unlist))` as suggested in another post, but the same error occurs.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Without the data I can't try anything myself, but what about using `train.user$age <- unlist(train.user$age)`? You don't want to store it back to a `data.frame`.

Comment: Please provide a sample data. Only then it is possible to work for a solution specific to your case.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanCarroll, the code you provided works! I'll summarize it later in the post for those who have same issue. However, I am still wondering what's the logic behind using `unlist` (and why list is not accepted?). It would be great if you could explain more about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
train.user$age <- unlist(train.user$age)
```

Technically, a `data.frame` is a list of equal-length vectors, but most functions will assume that all of the columns are atomic vectors and will fail when you try to use a list.

NB: Don't edit an answer into your question.

Answer (score 0):

pacman::p_load(tidyverse)

train.user %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(age = map(age,~unlist(.)))